# Dynamic update Ul Li using javascript ( mootools 1.2 )

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have one form which is submitting by ajax.

I am running on php.

After the entry completed by ajax, that entry should be updated to my html.
For example

My HTML Code

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Now when any one insert new entry with 5, then my html should be updated with below HTML.

```
<ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it my own.

Please check the below code for the answer.

```
// Select UL to append    
var commentUL = $('comment_ul');

//Create new li to insert
    var commentnewLI = new Element('li', {id: 'myFirstElement'});
// Append text to li
    commentnewLI.appendText(responseValueArray[1]);
// Insert li into UL
    commentUL.adopt(commentnewLI);
```

Mootools' admopt method has works for me.

But i have some problem regarding this.

My response has some HTML in the to append in the LI.
Like below

```
Dummy text, Dummy text,Dummy text,<br/><span>User Name</span>
```

Can u please suggest that whats the problem over here.

Thanks
Avinash

Answer (score 0):

Using the "dollar" function to select and extend the `UL`, then using one of MooTool's Element methods to insert the new `LI` will probably work.

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#dollar

http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:inject

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i have solved it my own..
But i have some problem regarding that, can u please look at that....

Answer (score 0):

My HTML problem is solved.

I have just replace the

```
commentnewLI.appendText(responseValueArray[1]);
```

with below code.

```
commentnewLI.innerHTML= responseValueArray[1];
```

Its working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

```
//the list
<ul id='the_list'>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li id='template_row' class='hidden'>list template. Can have <span class='bold'>HTML</span></li>
</ul>

//get the template
var template = $('template_row');
//create a new row, based on the template
var newRow = new Element('li').set('html', template.innerHTML);
//add it to the list
newRow.inject($('the_list'));
```

My template row has HTML and it is rendered properly.